# Search for function in Object and list its path

Tags: function, object, path, tree, find

I have an object with different attributes and functions.
My object looks like the following: data.user.identification
Now this object has a function somewhere in his tree called "GetName"

This function can be always in various attributes, for example:

data.user.identification.ys.z.GetName 
OR 
data.user.identification.dkz.ys.GetName 
OR 
data.user.identification.list.blub.GetName 
Now I have to know in which path this function is. 
For example: data.user.identification.ys.z.GetName 
I hope somebody can help me further with this?

I'm using Javascript.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using javascript

Comment: What form should the path take?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question. I should get the Path as a string.
There are always two attributes after my object (for example data.user.identification.X.X and then the function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myfind( obj, name ) { 
    // Check all of the elements of obj
    for ( var k in obj ) { 
        if ( k == name ) { 
            // It is the one we're looking for
            return k; 
        } else { 
            // Find the path within this element
            var path = myfind( obj[k], name ); 
            if ( path ) {
                // We found it; return path to it from this element
                return k + "." + path; 
             } 
        } 
    }
    // We didn't find it
    return undefined;
}
```

Note that the path returned will *not* include the name of the original object, but the caller knows that & can add it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott!
I called the function with myfind("data.user.identification", "GetName")
Unfortunately I got the error: InternalError: too much recursion
Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are passing a string, not the actual object, for the first argument.